# Debian XFCE screen locking and session logout

Tags: linux, debian, screensaver, xfce, xscreensaver

I am using **Debian 9**, **kernel 4.9.0-1** and **xfce 4.12.3** and I have a problem that after I lock the screen and close the lid of my laptop and later open the lid I will be prompted with the session login (same login that prompts the first time I boot into the system) and after that with the screen locker. Is there a way to disable this session login and only have screen locker because it is tiresome to type username and password every time I close the lid.

Comment: In settings manager choose "Session and Startup" and on "general" tab uncheck "Display chooser on login" but it will remove screen locker functionality too. It kinda controversial - remove login protection and keep it in the same time

Comment: It is already unchecked.

Comment: Check power setting, it is in settings manager/Power Manager there should be settings in action panel for "When laptop lid closed" choose appropriate action you want

Comment: It it set to lock the screen, but the problem is that beside locking the screen I get like logout. I am prompted with username and password to enter instead of xscreensaver window where I need to enter password. After I enter username and password then xscreensaver window shows and I need to enter password once again. I want to bypass entering password two times.

Comment: Choose "suspend" instead of "lock screen" in power manager

Comment: But I do not want to suspend when I close the lid. I just want to lock the screen.

Comment: What do you want - lock the screen and don't provide password? If you want to lock the screen then you MUST provide unlocking credentials in the same way as you login first time

Comment: At the moment when I close the lid, and than open it again I am prompted first with [login screen](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eAHujXXTGfo/maxresdefault.jpg) and after that with [lock screen](http://linuxscoop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Fedora-21-XFCE-Lock-Screen.jpg). What I want is to only have lock screen.

Answer (score 9):

In settings manager "Session and Startup" choose the "Application Autostart" tab and uncheck "Screen Locker" - keep "Screensaver" checked

Here is the screenshot.
Menu > Sessions Startup > Application Autostart

[image: Sessions_Startup_pic]

Answer (score 1):

Also check the Xfce Power Manager, on the Security tab, there is a dropdown for 'Automatically lock the screen ' and a checkbox for 'Lock screen when system is going for sleep' as these could also be locking your screen.